# Laravel config helper not being set

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I want to set variables using the Laravel config helper function to get the value of a configuration variable. The version of Laravel I'm currently using is Laravel 6.6.0. However, there are no errors and it's not working for me because the variable doesn't change.

```php
config(['world.name' => 'foo']);
```

Or

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

Config::set('world.name' , 'foo');
```

Comment: This will only change it for the current request. If you want to change it permanently, you'll need to have your code modify the actual config files.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks , now i get it , its just for runtime.

Comment: Cool. I'll add that as an answer, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing via the `config` helper or `Config` class only affects the current request. These changes are not persisted.

To persist them, you'll need to modify the `config/world.php` or `.env` files, or have the configuration load at runtime from something like a database.

Answer (score 0):

This how you can call a conf. parameter
First you have to create a class or use a current class inside conf directory, for example let use **services.php**

```
'welcome' => [
    'name' => 'Joe Doe',
]
```

Then you can call anywhere like.

```
config('services.welcone.name' ,'Foo'), // First it will check if name parameter is set, otherwise use Foo
```

Or if `welcome` is class than you do it this way:

```
 'name' => 'Joe Doe',
 config('welcone.name' ,'Foo')
```